# Cant display return value on html page

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an app that's meant to display the result of a balanced scale based on a number of inputs but I don't seem to be able to display the values on the HTML page.

I've run on the console and in codepen.io's console it works just fine but wont display in html page. I also attempted calling the function within the html tag but no headway. Any help will be appreciated.

here's my code

```
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = 
function(){
      let result = '';
      let input= document.getElementById("left").value;
      let check = input.split(',');
      if(check.length !== 2){
        result = " Wrong Input, Input can and must be two digits"
      }
      //return;


      let weigh = document.getElementById("weights-array").value;
      let checkWeight= weigh.split(',');
      if(checkWeight.length < 2){
        result = " Wrong Input, Input  must be greater than two digits"
      }
      let arr = [check, checkWeight];
      return;


    function balanceScale(arr){

        //Firstly, we need to convert our strings to numbers we can use in the Array

        let scaleWeights = arr[0].match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

        let weights = arr[1].match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

        let leftSide = scaleWeights[0];

        let rightSide = scaleWeights[1];

        // Secondly, we check for adding weight to one side of the scale i.e leftside or rightside
        for(let i = 0; i < weights.length; i++){
            if(leftSide < rightSide){
                if(leftSide + weights[i] === rightSide){
                  result = weights[i];
                    return result;

                }else if(rightSide + weights[i] === leftSide){
                    result = weights[i];
                    return result;

                }
            }
        }

        //Thirdly, we check for adding weights to both sidess of the scale ie. leftside && rightside
        let i,j;
        for(i = 0; i < weights.length; i++){
            for(j =0; j < weights.length[i]; j++){
                if(leftSide + weights[i] === rightSide + weights[j]){
                  result = weights[i] + ' ' + weights[j];
                  return result;
                }else if(rightSide + weights[i] === leftSide + weights[j]){
                  result = weights[i] + ' ' + weights[j];
                  return result;
                }
            }
        }

        //Lastly we check to add (2) two weights to one side of the scale
        if( leftSide + weights[i] + weights[j] === rightSide){
          result = weights[i] + ' ' + weights[j];
          return result;

        }else if (rightSide + weights[i] + weights[j] === leftSide){
          result = weights[i] + ' ' + weights[j];
          return result;

        }
        // if there are no matching weights
        result = "Scale Imbalanced";
        return result;
      }
      document.getElementById("displayresult").innerHTML = result;

    }
     console.log(balanceScale(["[3, 6]", "[1, 2, 7, 7]"]));



<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title> Scale Balancing</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <section id = 'head-sect'>
          <h1> Scale Balancing</h1>
        </section>

          <p> Insert an input weight into both sides of the scale.</p>

            <label for= "scaler"> Scale </label>
            <input type = 'text' id ='left' placeholder = 'Type scale Array' required><br><br>

            <label for = "weights"> Weights</weights>
            <input type = "text" id ="weights-array" placeholder = "Type weight Array" required><br><br>
             <button id="submit"> Calculate</button><br><span><br>

          <div id="displayresult">
            <script>
             document.getElementById("displayresult").innerHTML = result;
            </script>
          </div>


      </body>
    </html>

<!-- end snippet -->



      <p> Insert an input weight into both sides of the scale.</p>

        <label for= "scaler"> Scale </label>
        <input type = 'text' id ='left' placeholder = 'Type scale Array'   required><br><br>

        <label for = "weights"> Weights</weights>
        <input type = "text" id ="weights-array" placeholder = "Type weight Array" required><br><br>
         <button id="submit"> Calculate</button><br><span><br>

      <div id="displayresult">
        <script>
         document.getElementById("displayresult").innerHTML = result;
        </script>
      </div>

    and the JS code

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(){
  let result = '';
  let input= document.getElementById("left").value;
  let check = input.split(',');
  if(check.length !== 2){
    result = " Wrong Input, Input can and must be two digits"
  }
  //return;


  let weigh = document.getElementById("weights-array").value;
  let checkWeight= weigh.split(',');
  if(checkWeight.length < 2){
    result = " Wrong Input, Input  must be greater than two digits"
  }
  let arr = [check, checkWeight];
  return;


function balanceScale(arr){

    //Firstly, we need to convert our strings to numbers we can use in the Array

    let scaleWeights = arr[0].match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

    let weights = arr[1].match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

    let leftSide = scaleWeights[0];

    let rightSide = scaleWeights[1];

    // Secondly, we check for adding weight to one side of the scale i.e leftside or rightside
    for(let i = 0; i < weights.length; i++){
        if(leftSide < rightSide){
            if(leftSide + weights[i] === rightSide){
              result = weights[i];
                return result;

            }else if(rightSide + weights[i] === leftSide){
                result = weights[i];
                return result;

            }
        }
    }

    //Thirdly, we check for adding weights to both sidess of the scale ie. leftside && rightside
    let i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < weights.length; i++){
        for(j =0; j < weights.length[i]; j++){
            if(leftSide + weights[i] === rightSide + weights[j]){
              result = weights[i] + ' ' + weights[j];
              return result;
            }else if(rightSide + weights[i] === leftSide + weights[j]){
              result = weights[i] + ' ' + weights[j];
              return result;
            }
        }
    }

    //Lastly we check to add (2) two weights to one side of the scale
    if( leftSide + weights[i] + weights[j] === rightSide){
      result = weights[i] + ' ' + weights[j];
      return result;

    }else if (rightSide + weights[i] + weights[j] === leftSide){
      result = weights[i] + ' ' + weights[j];
      return result;

    }
    // if there are no matching weights
    result = "Scale Imbalanced";
    return result;
  }
  document.getElementById("displayresult").innerHTML = result;

}
 console.log(balanceScale(["[3, 6]", "[1, 2, 7, 7]"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in the code. glimpse of some fix.

```
let scaleWeights = parseFloat(arr[0])
let weights = parseFloat(arr[1]);

if (result == '') {
      document.getElementById("displayresult").innerHTML = balanceScale(arr);
 } else {
      document.getElementById("displayresult").innerHTML = result
 }
```

Attaching working jsfiddle .
https://jsfiddle.net/muneeburrahman/v5x9e4yz/1/